# Match all GET url using angular-mocks for backendless

Tags: javascript, ajax, regex, angularjs, angular-mock

I am writing a frontend without backend ajax for now. I am using `angular-mocks` to simulate API call like this:

```
$httpBackend.when('GET', '/somelink').respond(function(method, url, data) {
  //do something
});
```

However, if the ajax passes `params: {id:12345}`, it will append to the url to be `'/somelink?id=12345'`. That doesn't *catch* by the `when('GET', '/somelink')`

Is there a way to use RegEx or some trick to work around this? Just so that regardless of what is inside `params`, the `respond()` still gets called?

Thanks.

**UPDATE 1:**

I cannot use `.whenGET` because my backendless system has `POST` and `PUT` as well. So I need to keep it generic. This two params `.when('GET', '/somelink')` are actually variables in my code.

Since `'/somelink'` is a variable in another `JSON`, having RegEx `/\/somelink/` in JSON doesn't seem to work. At least that's what I see for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you can use a regex like this:

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/somelink/).respond(function(method, url, data) {
    //do something
});
```

**EDIT**

ok, you can do:

```
var method = 'GET';
var url = '/somelink';
$httpBackend.when(method, new RegExp('\\' + url)).respond(function(method, url, data) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: I like the simple solution

Comment: works great. a `)` is missing after '$httpBackend.when(method, new RegExp('\\' + url)).respond…`

Answer (score 3):

The url can be a `RegExp` object, or any object that has the method `test`.

To match query parameters, you can use the following:

```
var somelinkPattern = /^\/somelink(?:\?(.*))?$/;
$httpBackend.when('GET', somelinkPattern).respond(function(method, url, data) {
  var query = somelinkPattern.exec(url)[1];
  // url = "/somelink?abc=123" -> query = "abc=123"
});
```

To create a pattern from a string url, with optional query-string, you could use this:

```
var targetUrl = "/somelink";
var pattern = new RegExp(
    "^" +
    targetUrl.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.\\^$|]/g, "\\$&") + /* escape special chars */
    "(?:\\?.*)?$");
$httpBackend.when('GET', pattern).respond(function(method, url, data) {
  var queryMatch = /^[^#]*\?([^#]*)/.exec(url);
  var query = queryMatch ? queryMatch[1] : "";
  // url = "/somelink?abc=123" -> query = "abc=123"
});
```